# Reorder Umbraco Razor Nodes

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to list all my featured news at the top but i can't get them in the right order. This is what i got:

> var featuredNewsCollection = allNewsCollection.Where(x =>
>   featuredNewsIds.Contains(x.Id));

This lists the featured news in the order they appear in allNewsCollection. I want them in the order they appear in featuredNewsIds int list. Is there a smart way to rearrange this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that:

```
var featuredNewsCollection = allNewsCollection.Where(x => featuredNewsIds.Contains(x.Id)).OrderBy(x => featuredNewsIds.IndexOf(x.Id));
```